# How did Jon Snow descend the wall in Season 3, Episode 7?

Tags: game-of-thrones, jon-snow

We see him climb the wall, but how did they come down? The same way they got up or are there any stairs belonging to the Night's Watch? If so, then why did the red-haired girl say "It's a long way up and a long way down" just in the prior episode?

Comment: Can't cite show references off the top of my head but in the books, implication is that each castle has stairs carved out of ice and wood that lead all the way up to the wall. Some like Castle Black have lifts as well as stairs. Only three castles were manned by NW when the raiders slipped through. All the raiders needed to do was to walk atop the wall (Which is wide enough for a couple of horses to run abreast) to the nearest abandoned castle and make their descent. Scaling would be too dangerous without trees to give them a boost.

Comment: "A long way down" clearly refers to falling. A cliche line appearing in pretty much every movie or series where the protagonists are high up for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

From *A Storm of Swords*:

> They had descended the south face of the Wall at Greyguard, abandoned for two hundred years. A section of the huge stone steps had collapsed a century before, but even so the descent was a good deal easier than the climb.

Greyguard being an abandoned castle of the Night's Watch, which would have stairs on the south side.